# Transporting someone else's goods across US border

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

I'm a Canadian living in the US. My parents (also Canadian) are driving down to visit me and are bringing some furniture of mine down to deliver to me. A couple months ago they tried something similar and crossing the US border became a huge ordeal because the border guards said they weren't allowed to transport my stuff without me being there. My parents were told that there is some form they could have filled out to make this process easier; however, I can't find any reference to such a form online. Anyone know how to transport someone else's stuff into the US? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done this once, [the FAQ entry I worked from is here](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/440/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNTAwODcwNjgxL3NpZC8yUW83Vm1vbg%3D%3D). Your parents need to have:

- A notarized letter from you authorizing your parents to carry the stuff on your behalf.
- A copy of your passport name page and anything you have showing your status in the US.
- A list of every item they are bringing for you. The more detailed and organized the list is, the less likely they are to bother checking it.
- A filled in CBP Form 3299 signed by you.

If you brought it yourself you would still need the list and your documents showing status, but you'd fill out a CBP Form 6059B instead.

Comment: Would it be better or worse if you 'gave' this stuff to your parents, have them drive 'their' stuff over the border and then 'give' the stuff to you? In other words, is it less bureaucratic from them to carry stuff they own which they intend to give away?

Comment: Worse.  They will get all sorts of questions as to why they are importing this property only to give it away.  The goods may be subject to taxes and duties depending on their origin.